# upload a large file over 1GB to 2GB using jQuery File Upload - blueimp (Ajax based) php / yii it showing error in Firefox Browser

Tags: php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, jquery-file-upload, large-files

I am trying to upload a large file over `1GB` to `2GB` using `jQuery File Upload - blueimp` (Ajax based)  `php / yii Framework 1.15` i have set these values to upload larger file

```
memory_limit = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M 
post_max_size = 2048M
```

**Session time set**

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7200);
```

I test lesser than `1GB` file that is uploading successfully

when I am trying to upload larger than `1GB` file it shows Forbidden error after 50mins uploading time...

**Server Specifications**

- it's a virtual machine, and due to it's not production yet so we only
  using `1CPU` and `1GB memory`, 64bit

File uploading is working in `Google Chrome`and `Microsoft Edge`(I have tested with 1.15 and 1.88 GB file) when I am uploading file in `Mozilla Firefox` less than 300MB it is uploading successfully but when I am trying yo upload greater than 300MB file after some time Ajax call is fails and give `500 Internal Server Error`
header response is in below image 
[image: header response]

Comment: Your server will be the issue then, it tries to store the file in memory (you've only got 1gig), my suggestion would be to use something like wamp or xampp on a machine with more memory and try that

Comment: check web server error logs. There will be the exact error. It can be a time out or size limit.

Comment: Check your yii configuration for session timeout value, this should also be 7200. Also check where you login the user, in this call you can also [set a timeout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail)

Comment: Oky @Harikrishnan let me check server logs

Comment: @Harikrishnan 
session.gc_maxlifetime
Local Value = 7200, master Value = 1440

session.cookie_lifetime
Local Value = 7200, master Value = 0

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue without using chunked uploads. I am facing the exact same issue with firefox.

Answer (score 8):

When you upload files having size more than 100 MB, better go for [chunked file uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads). jQuery-File-Upload supports that.

It splits files into smaller fragments with predefined chunk size and upload them one by one. Another advantage is that you can resume file uploads. No need to upload entire file  again, if the upload is interrupted. Also it can overcome your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`  issue.

Comment: very nice suggestions